# No feedback from Image Uploader

Tags: forms, files, media

i've setup a content type that contains two image fields. One for a main image and the second for 4 smaller images. The trouble i'm having is when you select your image and click upload, there is no response from the browser.

So instead of this:

[image]

I get this:
[image]

Interestingly enough, the images to actually upload, it just doesn't tell the user. Now that wouldn't have been an issue but the second image field requires the user to upload more than one image but because nothing changes, they are unable to.

The only way to add another image is to edit the content and then go and add the second image (and repeat if more images are required). I must have done something wrong?

Just checked the console and I get this JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.js:583
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:583
Drupal.behaviors.conditionalFields.attach conditional_fields.js?n4i4te:122
(anonymous function) drupal.js?n4i4te:76
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:605
Drupal.attachBehaviors drupal.js?n4i4te:74
Drupal.ajax.commands.insert ajax.js?v=7.26:542
Drupal.ajax.success ajax.js?v=7.26:400
ajax.options.success ajax.js?v=7.26:164
options.success jquery.form.js?v=2.69:150
cb jquery.form.js?v=2.69:401
```

Issue may be related to:
https://drupal.org/node/1789040

**UPDATE:**
Deactivating the Conditional Fields module fixes the issue but there must be another way?

Comment: Are any JavaScript errors occurring during upload? I ask because I seem to remember this happening to me and was caused by a js error in tinymce not being compatible with the version of jQuery I was using.

Comment: Does disabling the conditional fields module solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it does!...Is there no other way? Really need the conditional fields module :/

Comment: The only other way is to actually go and **fix** conditional fields module, if it conflicts with core (and it seems it does). Have you posted bugreport?

Comment: The other thing I would suggest is installing the [7.x-3.x-dev](https://drupal.org/node/1137614) version of conditional fields - the bug causing this issue may have been fixed in that release.

Comment: I'm a little sceptical about using dev versions of modules as this site is about to go live over the weekend - I would prefer removing conditional fields until it is fixed rather than risk it.